# Xamarin page loads but doesn't show up on screen

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem with my program getting stuck at the await Pushmodalasync part. It's supposed to get stuck there until you login into the application, but the loginpage never loads, it's just stuck at the loading screen.

It's the same problem on iOS and Android.

Loading the login page

```cs
protected async override void OnAppearing()
{
    if (App.Client.Initilized == false)
    {
        await App.Client.Init();
    }

    if (App.Client.LoggedIn == false)
    {
        ShowLoginPage();
        return;
    }

    ShowIssuesFromCurrentLocation();
}
```

Calling the login page

```cs
private async void ShowLoginPage()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<LoginPage>(this, "OnLoginPageClosed", (sender) =>
    {
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<LoginPage>(this, "OnLoggedIn");

        if (App.Client.LoggedIn == false)
        {
            Issues.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            ShowIssuesFromCurrentLocation();
        }
    });

    await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());
}
```

The loginpage itself

```cs
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public LoginViewModel data;
    public LoginViewModel Data { get { return data; } }
    public LoginPage()
    {
        this.data = App.Client.GetCurrentLoginModel();
        this.BindingContext = this.data;
        this.Title = "Login";
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The xaml part of the login class

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ASFT.IssueManager.LoginPage" Padding="10">
  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <x:String x:Key="Labelfont">Medium</x:String>
      <x:String x:Key="Titlefont">Large</x:String>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </ContentPage.Resources>
  <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="10" >
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center" Spacing="10" WidthRequest="350">
      <Label Text="Login" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="{StaticResource Titlefont}"/>
      <BoxView HeightRequest="5" Color="Gray"/>
      <Label Text="Host" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="{StaticResource Labelfont}"/>
      <Entry Placeholder="Host/URL" Text="{Binding Host}" />
      <Label Text="UserName" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="{StaticResource Labelfont}"/>
      <Entry Placeholder="User name / Account" Text="{Binding Username}" />
      <Label Text="Password" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Start" FontSize="{StaticResource Labelfont}"/>
      <Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="true" Text="{Binding Password}" />
      <BoxView HeightRequest="5" Color="Gray"/>
      <Button x:Name="btnLogin" Text="Login" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Clicked="OnButtonLogin" WidthRequest="100"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

InitializeComponent method

[global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.XamlG", "0.0.0.0")]
         private void InitializeComponent() {
                    global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(LoginPage));
                    btnLogin = global::Xamarin.Forms.NameScopeExtensions.FindByName(this, "btnLogin");
                }

The loginview model

```cs
public LoginViewModel GetCurrentLoginModel()
    {
      // DEBUG
      if (state.Username.Length == 0)
        state.Username = "mudemo";
      if (state.Host.Length == 0)
        state.Host = "";

      // VERY DEBUG. - REMOVE 
      //String password = "4R5zE6mw";
      String password = "mudemo";

      return new LoginViewModel
      {
        // default debug account
        Host = state.Host,
        Username = state.Username,
        Password = password
      };
    }
```

Error message:

I'm using xamarinsforms 2.5.0.12, the latest stable available.

> 12-14 12:21:15.185 D/AbsListView(22659): unregisterIRListener() is
>   called  12-14 12:21:15.190 D/Mono    (22659): DllImport searching in:
>   '__Internal' ('(null)'). 12-14 12:21:15.190 D/Mono    (22659):
>   Searching for 'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'.
>   12-14 12:21:15.190 D/Mono    (22659): Probing
>   'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'. 12-14
>   12:21:15.190 D/Mono    (22659): Found as
>   'java_interop_jnienv_call_nonvirtual_float_method_a'. 12-14
>   12:21:15.220 D/Mono    (22659): DllImport searching in: '__Internal'
>   ('(null)'). 12-14 12:21:15.220 D/Mono    (22659): Searching for
>   'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'. 12-14 12:21:15.225 D/Mono
>   (22659): Probing 'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'. 12-14
>   12:21:15.225 D/Mono    (22659): Found as
>   'java_interop_jnienv_call_void_method'. 12-14 12:21:15.280
>   D/AbsListView(22659): unregisterIRListener() is called  12-14
>   12:21:19.350 D/Mono    (22659): Unloading image
>   System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll [0x8356da00]. 12-14 12:21:19.350 D/Mono
>   (22659): Image addref System.Diagnostics.Debug[0x8356ac40] ->
>   System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll[0x7fbf0d28]: 5 12-14 12:21:19.350 D/Mono 
>   (22659): Config attempting to parse:
>   'System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll.config'. 12-14 12:21:19.350 D/Mono
>   (22659): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Diagnostics.Debug/System.Diagnostics.Debug.config'.
>   12-14 12:21:19.350 D/Mono    (22659): Assembly Ref addref
>   ASFT.IssueManager[0x7db3d5c0] -> System.Diagnostics.Debug[0x7fc01d28]:
>   3 Resolved pending breakpoint at 'LoginPage.xaml.cs:32,1' to void
>   ASFT.IssueManager.LoginPage.OnDisappearing () [0x0000d]. Resolved
>   pending breakpoint at 'LoginPage.xaml.cs:31,1' to void
>   ASFT.IssueManager.LoginPage.OnDisappearing () [0x00001]. 12-14
>   12:21:24.365 D/Mono    (22659): Image addref
>   System.Diagnostics.Tools[0x83567040] ->
>   System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll[0x835676b0]: 2 12-14 12:21:24.365 D/Mono 
>   (22659): Prepared to set up assembly 'System.Diagnostics.Tools'
>   (System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll) 12-14 12:21:24.365 D/Mono    (22659):
>   Assembly System.Diagnostics.Tools[0x83567040] added to domain
>   RootDomain, ref_count=1 12-14 12:21:24.365 D/Mono    (22659): AOT:
>   image 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll.so' not found: dlopen failed:
>   library
>   "/data/app-lib/com.asft.event-68/libaot-System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll.so"
>   not found 12-14 12:21:24.365 D/Mono    (22659): AOT: image
>   '/usr/local/lib/mono/aot-cache/arm/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll.so'
>   not found: dlopen failed: library
>   "/data/app-lib/com.asft.event-68/libaot-System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll.so"
>   not found 12-14 12:21:24.365 D/Mono    (22659): Config attempting to
>   parse: 'System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll.config'. 12-14 12:21:24.365
>   D/Mono    (22659): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Diagnostics.Tools/System.Diagnostics.Tools.config'.
>   12-14 12:21:24.365 D/Mono    (22659): Assembly Ref addref
>   ASFT.IssueManager[0x7db3d5c0] -> System.Diagnostics.Tools[0x83567040]:
>   2 12-14 12:21:24.365 D/Mono    (22659): Assembly Ref addref
>   System.Diagnostics.Tools[0x83567040] -> System[0x7ed17940]: 12 12-14
>   12:21:26.585 W/Mono    (22659): The request to load the assembly
>   mscorlib v4.0.0.0 was remapped to v2.0.5.0 12-14 12:21:26.585 D/Mono
>   (22659): Unloading image mscorlib.dll [0x835670b0]. 12-14 12:21:26.585
>   D/Mono    (22659): Config attempting to parse: 'mscorlib.dll.config'.
>   12-14 12:21:26.585 D/Mono    (22659): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'. 12-14
>   12:21:26.585 D/Mono    (22659): Unloading image
>   System.Globalization.dll [0x83579b48]. 12-14 12:21:26.585 D/Mono
>   (22659): Image addref System.Globalization[0x8357a8b0] ->
>   System.Globalization.dll[0x7f17f3d0]: 6 12-14 12:21:26.585 D/Mono
>   (22659): Config attempting to parse:
>   'System.Globalization.dll.config'. 12-14 12:21:26.585 D/Mono
>   (22659): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Globalization/System.Globalization.config'.
>   12-14 12:21:26.585 D/Mono    (22659): Assembly Ref addref
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0x7dbd5a78] -> System.Globalization[0x7f17ffd8]: 4
>   Loaded assembly: System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll [External] 12-14
>   12:21:26.600 W/Mono    (22659): The request to load the assembly
>   mscorlib v4.0.0.0 was remapped to v2.0.5.0 12-14 12:21:26.600 D/Mono
>   (22659): Unloading image mscorlib.dll [0x835670b0]. 12-14 12:21:26.600
>   D/Mono    (22659): Config attempting to parse: 'mscorlib.dll.config'.
>   12-14 12:21:26.600 D/Mono    (22659): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/mscorlib/mscorlib.config'. 12-14
>   12:21:26.805 D/Mono    (22659): Unloading image
>   System.Runtime.Extensions.dll [0x8359dec8]. 12-14 12:21:26.805 D/Mono 
>   (22659): Image addref System.Runtime.Extensions[0x83595340] ->
>   System.Runtime.Extensions.dll[0x7eb780b0]: 6 12-14 12:21:26.805 D/Mono
>   (22659): Config attempting to parse:
>   'System.Runtime.Extensions.dll.config'. 12-14 12:21:26.805 D/Mono
>   (22659): Config attempting to parse:
>   '/usr/local/etc/mono/assemblies/System.Runtime.Extensions/System.Runtime.Extensions.config'.
>   12-14 12:21:26.805 D/Mono    (22659): Assembly Ref addref
>   Xamarin.Forms.Xaml[0x7dbd5a78] ->
>   System.Runtime.Extensions[0x7eb77b68]: 4 12-14 12:21:31.060
>   I/Choreographer(22659): Skipped 946 frames!  The application may be
>   doing too much work on its main thread. 12-14 12:21:31.075
>   D/AbsListView(22659): unregisterIRListener() is called  Unhandled
>   Exception:
>
> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   source

App start

```cs
 public App()
    {
      Client = new AppIssueClient();
      // The root page of your application
      MainPage = GetMainPage();
    }

    public async void Init()
    {
      await Client.Init();
    }

    public static Page GetMainPage()
    {
      var p = new NavigationPage(new IssuesPage(-1));
      App.Navigation = p.Navigation;
      return p;//  new NavigationPage(new HomePage());
    }
```

Comment: You need to await ShowLoginPage() inside OnAppearing().

Comment: Hmm, all that did is make it crash after the return. A null-reference error due to lifecyclecallsbacks when an activity gets destroyed, can edit into the crash there

Comment: Can you show your LoginModel ?

Comment: I added the LoginModel, but I'm not sure if it will be relevant. :)

Comment: In your xaml you Binding username and password but in your ViewModel you don't have this field. And ViewModel have to implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: Interesting, how would you suggest implementing it?

Comment: Look at my answer and try it. Maybe it helps

Comment: what version of XF are you using?

Comment: @J.Dhaik pay attention to what you are posting, seems like your post contains a password. In order to help to solve the issue you have, will be nice to see a stacktrace. NullReferenceException does not tell much. Have you tried to debug your code? Where exactly the exception is thrown?

Comment: And in your error window you have innerExeption or something like this. And if you go in this there will be more info

Comment: Added more info, still trying to figure out how to get the stack trace though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple possible problems spotted in your code sample:

1. In the constructor of `LoginPage` `InitializeComponent();` should come first.
2. In `OnAppearing()` you have to `await ShowLoginPage();`, otherwise the code will continue the execution.
3. The exception is pointing towards XAML, try to enable [XAMLC](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xamlc/).

Try to eliminate the problems I spotted one by one, hopefully you will find a solution.

Comment: Ah, damn. Tried all of them. Didn't change much sadly.  Initalizecomopnent first just made it crash earlier. Not sure if XAMLC did anything, but I enabled it on the class level of the loginpage. I just don't get why it won't wait for my loginpage before continuing.

Comment: Comment out most of your code on the LoginPage and uncomment the lines one by one to see where the problem is. Does the crash happens on InitializeComponent? If so the problem is clearly in your XAML.

Comment: The crash actually happen after initalizecomponent. After initalizecomponent it returned to first await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage()); and then await ShowLoginPage(); and then crashes the next line.

Comment: What is set as App's MainPage? Does await ShowLoginPage(); showing a modal page or simply crashing instead?

Comment: It simply crashes instead. I edited into the mainpage start of the application, but the mainpage is a whole nother mess to get into and I hope it's not related. It loads another contentpage before which is where the onappearing is inside.

Comment: It is impossible to provide a solution this way. Clean up your solution step by step and simplify the code as much as possible, if LoginPage is throwing an exception try to create a blank page and show it instead of LoginPage. If it will work then copy the existing code from LoginPage line by line till the exception will be thrown. Otherwise all the answers and comments are simply pointless. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, I will! Very grateful for your help. :)

Comment: Tried as you said by the way! It was an xaml error! The crash location changed now, the source is null when initalizing the loginpage. Now I just have to find out how to fix that. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with load page and it was stop in launch page because I have problem with ViewModel. Can you show your LoginModel?

And try instead of this

```
await this.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LoginPage());
```

use:

```
MainPage = new LoginPage();
```

--EDIT
In Your ViewModel:

```
public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    String username;
    public String Username{
        get{
            return username;
        }set{
            username = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Username");
        }
    }

    String password;
    public String Password{
        get{
            return password;
        }set{
            password = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Password");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your ContentPage you use:

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
  public LoginViewModel data;
  public LoginViewModel Data { get { return data; } }
  public LoginPage()
  {
     //this.data = App.Client.GetCurrentLoginModel();
     this.BindingContext = new LoginViewModel() // or you get from App.cs
     this.Title = "Login";
     InitializeComponent();
 }
```

Comment: I know but I don't have 50 reputation and i can't comment in main post

Comment: Nicely done! However instead of being able to click the login button and enter your username/pW it just continues anways. :/

Comment: But you can in your ViewModel binding button click. But is it working now and you see your login page ?

Comment: Nope, still nothing there. Can't see the login page at all. :/